# Rspec 3.4/Rails 4.2: testing for flash message is failing in one spec, but not two others

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am using Rails 4.2 and Rspec 3.4.  I have 3 controller tests that test a flash message to see if the right message is being displayed.  Two of them are working and one is not.  I can't see the difference between the working ones and the not working one.

My controller looks like this:

```
before_filter :logged_in_as_team_member, except: [:index, :show, :choose_revisions_to_diff, :diff_results]

def destroy
  doc = Document.find(params[:id])
  if doc.owners.include?(@user) && !doc.document_revisions.any?
    doc.destroy
    redirect_to documents_url, notice: "Document successfully deleted."
  else
    redirect_to documents_url, flash: { error: "Could not delete document because you are not an owner or the document has revisions assigned to it." }
  end
end


private
def logged_in_as_team_member
  redirect_to root_url, flash: { error: "You must be a Devcomm team member to perform this action." } unless @user.is_devcomm
end
```

My Rspec looks like this:

```
describe "DELETE #destroy" do

  ### This test fails
  it "as devcomm when user is owner returns success" do
    devcomm_user
    delete :destroy, id: documents(:nonsecretdocument1)
    expect(response).to redirect_to(action: :index)
    expect(flash[:notice]).to match "Document successfully deleted."
  end

  ### This test passes
  it "as devcomm when user is not owner redirects to documents#index" do
    devcomm_user
    delete :destroy, id: documents(:nonsecretdocument2)
    expect(response).to redirect_to(action: :index)
    expect(flash[:error]).to match "Could not delete document because you are not an owner."
  end

  ### This test passes
  it "as nondevcomm redirects to root_url" do
    nondevcomm_user
    delete :destroy, id: documents(:nonsecretdocument2)
    expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url)
    expect(flash[:error]).to match "You must be a Devcomm team member to perform this action."
  end
end
```

The error:

```
Failures:

  1) DocumentsController DELETE #destroy as devcomm when user is owner returns success
     Failure/Error: expect(flash[:notice]).to match "Document successfully deleted."
       expected nil to match "Document successfully deleted."
     # ./spec/controllers/documents_controller_spec.rb:114:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Can anyone see why the first test fails and the other two pass?

Edited to add: When I delete a document in the UI, the flash appears as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I am using fixtures and had added another model.  This new model was dependent on `documents(:nonsecretdocument1)`, which caused the document to not get deleted due to a constraint I have on documents that are allowed to be deleted.

Comment: I find it's helpful to test the record you're modifying in controller actions. In this case, something like `expect{@record.reload}.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)`